# Passing a Button component as a child of Menu.Button and wrapper being a Fragment

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I'm trying to pass a button component as a children of `Menu.Button` component from HeadlessUI the following way:

```
return <Menu.Button as={Fragment}><MyButton /></Button>;
```

but it gives me an error:
[image: error message]

The `MyButton` component is a `<button></button>` HTML element in return statement.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.